# Image Capturing Android Issue

Tags: android, android-capture

I am trying to add the customer thumbnail to his account by capturing the photo and crop  the face through another activity.It works fine in emulator,but when run on actual device got error.Help needed.

```
public void imageload(View v)
    {
        switch (v.getId()) {


            case imageView_new_customer:
                final CharSequence[] options = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery", "Cancel"};

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
                builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        if (options[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
                            File directory = contextWrapper.getDir("Image", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                        } else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

                        } else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Cropping Activity:

```
if (getIntent().getStringExtra("Source").equals("camera"))
{
    // Set image for cropping
    ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
File directory = contextWrapper.getDir("Image", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());


for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
    if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
        f = temp;
        break;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{loginscreen.example.com.girviapp/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp.CropImage}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2555)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2629)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:182)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5706)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1033)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
            at loginscreen.example.com.girviapp.CropImage.onCreate(CropImage.java:43)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2502)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2629)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:182)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5706)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1033)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with CropImage.java line 43 but I can't see the source to say what the issue might be other than the stack trace saying it's calling .length() on a null array

Comment: for (File temp : f.listFiles()), this is line 43

Comment: Check that f is actually being populated correctly. Also, have you declared the write_external_storage permission in your android manifest? On top of that, if youre targeting API 23 or above you'll need to request that same permission from the user.

Comment: I guess you really need the read storage permission but write will give you both read and write

Comment: I changed the permission from read to write still not working

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() returns a file object. so theres no need for you to be calling toString on it and creating a file object. That is your first fix. If you're looking for images you should maybe do

File f = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

or

File f = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

Answer (score 0):

You are converting thr uri to string in that line remove .toString() method instead use a path of your image like
File f=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/your_directory_name");

Answer (score 0):

```
1.<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

2.public int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0, SELECT_FILE = 1;    
 final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
            "Cancel"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                userChoosenTask = "Take Photo";
                if (result)
                    cameraIntent();
            } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                userChoosenTask = "Choose from Library";
                if (result)
                    galleryIntent();
            } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
3. private void cameraIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        String fileName = "temp.jpg";
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
        uri = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                values);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }
}
4.private void galleryIntent() {
    Intent intentPickImage = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intentPickImage, SELECT_FILE);
}
5.@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
            onCaptureImageResult(data);
        }  else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You haven't picked Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
6.private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
    if (data != null) {
        try {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);

            if (cursor == null || cursor.getCount() < 1) {
                return; // no cursor or no record. DO YOUR ERROR HANDLING
            }
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            PicturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            if (columnIndex < 0) // no column index
                return; // DO YOUR ERROR HANDLING
            String image = getStringImage(bitmap);
            PicturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            String filename=PicturePath.substring(PicturePath.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
            txtFilePath.setText(filename);
            cursor.close(); // close cursor
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Data Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
7. public void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(uri, projection, null,
            null, null);
    int column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    PicturePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
    String filename=PicturePath.substring(PicturePath.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    txtFilePath.setText(filename);
}
```